# Vuex token is null right after login

Tags: vue.js, axios, vuex

I'm using Axios and Vuex (with the "vuex-persistedstate" plugin) to make API calls and save data in local storage.

The problem is that right after the login the user token I get from the authentication call is null. I mean, the token is saved in the local storage but is null in the component. If I refresh the page, everything works fine.

I solved using an interceptor that injects the token for each call, but I would like to save the token as a GET parameter of my Axios instance.

```js
...
const apiClient = axios.create({
  baseURL: constants.MOODLE_WS_URL,
  params: {
    moodlewsrestformat: "json",
    // If I put the token here, it's saved but null right after the login
  },
});

// Workaround to avoid null token right after login
apiClient.interceptors.request.use(
  (config) => {
    const token = store.state.moodleWSToken;
    if (token) {
      config.params.wstoken = token;
    }
    return config;
  },
  (error) => {
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);
...
```

Any suggestion?

Thank you!